# chromatic index of the Johnson graph $J(5,2)$

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

The Johnson graph $J(5,2)$ is the line graph of $K_5$ and is a $6$-regular graph on $10$ vertices and $30$ edges. As $K_5$ has chromatic index $5$ so the chromatic number of $J(5,2)$ is $\chi(J(5,2))=5$.

By Vizing's theorem the chromatic index of $J(5,2)$ is $6$ or $7$. I want to know whether it is known.

Comment: By Vizing's theorem the chromatic index of $J(5,2)$ is $4$ or $5$, because $4$ is the maximal degree of vertices of $K_5$.

Comment: @Wolfram: Vizing's theorem has to be applied to $J(5,2)$ which is $6$-regular.

Comment: "The edges of every simple undirected graph may be colored using a number of colors that is at most one larger than the maximum degree $\Delta$ of the graph." If we color the vertices of $J(5,2)$, then we apply the theorem to $K_5$, if we color the edges of $J(5,2)$, then, yes, we need $6$ or $7$ colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My computer found a 6-edge-coloring of Johnson(5,2) using a backtracking algorithm:

[image: A 6-edge-coloring of Johnson(5,2)]

I acknowledge the use of [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) and the graph package Grape.  Here's my code:

```
EdgeSet:=function(G)
  return Concatenation(List(Vertices(G),v1->List(Adjacency(G,v1),v2->[v1,v2])));
end;;

RequirePackage("grape");
G:=JohnsonGraph(5,2);
F:=Filtered(EdgeSet(G),i->i[2]>i[1]);
Cols:=List([1..30],i->0);

NewColor:=function(i)
  local c,n;

  for c in [1..6] do
    if(ForAny([1..i-1],j->Intersection(F[i],F[j])<>[] and Cols[j]=c)) then continue; fi;
    Cols[i]:=c;

    if(i=30) then
      return Cols;
    else
      n:=NewColor(i+1);
      if(n<>fail) then return n; fi;
    fi;

    Cols[i]:=0;
  od;
  return fail;
end;;
```